# Intro.js not working for specific classes

Tags: intro.js

I'm not able to start the intro for elements only with class 'case_event_intro' but when I do `introJs(".case_event_intro").start();` nothing happens, even though there are elements with that class and with the intro att. defined (data-intro and data-step). The elements have also other classes apart case_event_intro. Could that be the problem? Are there any other conditions to make the intro work for only some elements with a given class?

See this [screen capture](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6421243/Intro.js%20not%20working%20for%20specific%20class.png).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In current version of IntroJs (v0.3.0) you cannot start introduction for specific element with a class or something.

You should create a container element, and then start introduction for those elements like this:

```
<div class="case_event_intro">
    <div data-intro="Hello world" data-step="1">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

And then call:

```
introJs(".case_event_intro").start();
```

Comment: Would 
<div class="case_event_intro">
    <div data-intro="Hello world" data-step="1">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="case_event_intro">
    <div data-intro="Hello world" data-step="2">
    </div>
</div>
Work?

Comment: @FernandoCMartinelli It works also yes, but IntroJs starts the introduction for both container and the same time. I mean for the first `div class="case_event_intro"` and for the second one also, at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Switch where you are adding the class.

```
introJs().start('.case_event_intro');
```