# intro.js not working for specific elements based on classes

Tags: javascript, intro.js

I am not able to start `intro.js`  with specific elements which are have `class='test'`.I am using `Intro.js v0.9.0`.

as per documentation, I written code just like following way.

```
 <li class="test" data-intro="first Step" data-step="1"><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Chart" id="chart-btn"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-lg"></i></a></li>
 <li class="test123" data-intro="first Step" data-step="1"><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Reset" id="reset"><i class="fa fa-repeat fa-lg"></i></a></li>
 <li class="test" data-intro="second Step" data-step="2"><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Compute" id="category"><i class="fa fa-play fa-lg"></i></a></li>
```

I tried to start `intro` like this

```
 introJs(".test").start();
```

It's not working.I goggled some guys suggested regarding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026600/intro-js-not-working-for-specific-classes),I tried those ways also but it's not working.

How can I fix this.

Answer (score 10):

I implemented with `steps`which is provided by `intro.js` plugin option like in the 
following way.

```
 var intro = introJs();
      intro.setOptions({
        steps: [
          { 
            intro: "Hello world!"
          },
          {
            element: document.getElementById("step1"),
            intro: "This is a tooltip."
          },
          {
            element: document.querySelectorAll('#step2')[0],
            intro: "Ok, wasn't that fun?",
            position: 'right'
          },
          {
            element: '#step3',
            intro: 'More features, more fun.',
            position: 'left'
          },
          {
            element: '#step4',
            intro: "Another step.",
            position: 'bottom'
          },
          {
            element: '#step5',
            intro: 'Get it, use it.'
          }
        ],
        showStepNumbers:false
      });

      intro.start();
```

Comment: You are using an ID where is the class?

Comment: thank you, really helped, I used 'document.querySelectorAll('.sftpImport.step1')[0]' for addressing multiple scenarios steps by classes

Answer (score 2):

If you see the you can see that the introJs parameter is for the farm of the steps/elements. So your code should be something like:

```
<div class='test'>
   <div class="span6 test" data-step="2" data-intro="Ok, wasn't that fun?">
        <h4>Easy to Use</h4>
      </div>
  </div>
```

And now introJs('.test').start(); should work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a complete example after you include/link the intro.js and introjs.css files to your project

```
$(document).ready(function startIntro() {
    var intro = introJs('body');
    intro.setOptions({
        steps: [
                  {
                      intro: "Hello world!"
                  },
                  {
                      intro: "You <b>don't need</b> to define element to focus, this is a floating tooltip."
                  },
                  {
                      element: document.querySelector('#step1'),
                      intro: "This is a tooltip."
                  },
                  {
                      element: document.querySelectorAll('#step2')[0],
                      intro: "Ok, wasn't that fun?",
                      position: 'right'
                  },
                  {
                      element: '#step3',
                      intro: 'More features, more fun.',
                      position: 'left'
                  },
                  {
                      element: '#step4',
                      intro: "Another step.",
                      position: 'bottom'
                  },
                  {
                      element: '#step5',
                      intro: 'Get it, use it.'
                  }
            ]
    });
    intro.start();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the new API they provided, [introducing an example](https://github.com/usablica/intro.js/blob/master/example/groups/index.html) of `group` feature. So, your example could work if you added an attribute called `data-intro-group` and handle the group name, like this:

```
<li data-intro-group="test" class="test" data-intro="first Step" data-step="1"><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Chart" id="chart-btn"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-lg"></i></a></li>
<li data-intro-group="test123" class="test123" data-intro="first Step" data-step="1"><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Reset" id="reset"><i class="fa fa-repeat fa-lg"></i></a></li>
<li data-intro-group="test" class="test" data-intro="second Step" data-step="2"><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Compute" id="category"><i class="fa fa-play fa-lg"></i></a></li>
```

Then, start `intro` for the specific group let's say `test` by: `introJs().start('test');`

Hope this helps!

Comment: this one worked best for me and I can't find the docs for it anywhere on introjs.com so thanks!